# Which forum should I use for Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, forum

I need to choose a forum component for a new Joomla installation and I'm wondering which one should I use:

- JoomlaBoard
- Joomla phpBB
- Joomla SMF
- Any other you might want to suggest

Among the requisites, I will need to dynamically create/delete forums and to add/delete members, so a forum that offers high level API for these tasks would be great. I can live with writing by myself the scripts to directly edit the database, though.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kunena! http://www.kunena.com/

Answer (score 0):

I used ccBoard http://codeclassic.org/ and is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

My best success has been with the Joomla Forum

http://forum.joomla.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would personally choose Kunena or PHPBB.

Both are fast, powerful but both have a few set backs. Kunena integrates with Joomla very easily, all you have to do is install and configure. has to be installed on a subdomain then integrated using a bridge, however is does have some features that Kunena doesnt like usergroups.

I personally use Kunena cause I love the simplicity and integration.